# WP Better Emails Plugin - HTML Template issue

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html-email

I'm having a problem with styling the email thru the HTML Template of the WP Better Emails Plugin.. I'm receiving the email alright but the style I placed under the Plain-text Template textarea is not working.. This is the code:

```
<html>
<body>
<p style="background-color: Gainsboro; color: DodgerBlue;">%content%</p>
</body>
</html>
```

It's a very simple code for now to test this feature. But it's not showing the background color and text color on my email..

EDIT:
I just found out that this plugin has this rule: HTML emails are not wrapped if they are already "text/html".
Unfortunately, I really need to have `<ul>` and `<li>` tags on my email without the style yet or else they'll look bad since there's no way for me to arrange or style those lists  without these tags that I can target with css. How can I get away with this rule? Any idea?

Comment: is the email being sent via HTML?

Comment: @RobertLee it's sent via wp_mail

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Contact Form 7. Its a contact form plugin for Wordpress and quite powerfull.

here is link:http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

Hope this help you. :)